# DataTables warning: JSON data from server could not be parsed.

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, datatable

This is caused by a JSON formatting error, in `asp.net mvc3`.
it was running in visual studio 2012 but not in visual studio 2013

```
    {"sEcho":"1","iTotalRecords":7,"iTotalDisplayRecords":7,"aaData":
[{"DeductionId":1,"DeductionName":"PAG-IBIG LOAN","IsActive":true},
{"DeductionId":2,"DeductionName":"SSS LOAN","IsActive":true},
{"DeductionId":3,"DeductionName":"CASH ADVANCE","IsActive":true},
{"DeductionId":4,"DeductionName":"HEALTH CARE","IsActive":true},
{"DeductionId":5,"DeductionName":"HOSPITAL LOAN","IsActive":true},
{"DeductionId":6,"DeductionName":"CANTEEN A","IsActive":true},
{"DeductionId":7,"DeductionName":"CANTEEN B","IsActive":true}]}
```

Comment: it was generating a special characters right after the json

Comment: thanks ehsan,  this was generated by my chrome browser when connecting to the visual studio 2013 iis {"sEcho":"1","iTotalRecords":7,"iTotalDisplayRecords":7,"aaData":[{"DeductionId":1,"DeductionName":"PAG-IBIG LOAN","IsActive":true},{"DeductionId":2,"DeductionName":"SSS LOAN","IsActive":true},{"DeductionId":3,"DeductionName":"CASH ADVANCE","IsActive":true},{"DeductionId":4,"DeductionName":"HEALTH CARE","IsActive":true},{"DeductionId":5,"DeductionName":B","IsActive":true}]}�����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������

Comment: how do get rid of the special characters